# IS IN (Select statement, 'value', 'value')

Tags: t-sql, select

I am trying to run the following SQL

```
DELETE FROM T_ATH_POSHLD WHERE T_ATH_POSHLD.A_INSID IN (SELECT T_ATH_POSHLD.A_INSID FROM T_ATH_POSHLD LEFT JOIN T_ATH_INS ON T_ATH_POSHLD.A_INSID = T_ATH_INS.A_INSID WHERE T_ATH_INS.A_INSCLSCDE1 = 'CASH' AND T_ATH_POSHLD.A_INSID NOT IN (SELECT A_INSID FROM T_ATH_CCY) AND A_ACCID IN (SELECT A_ACCID FROM T_ATH_EXTACC, '1212OEIC', '5667033ZS'))
```

and in particular, am trying to check whether an ACCID is in a set of values, some coming from a table and two hardcoded. How would I achieve this?

```
IN (SELECT A_ACCID FROM T_ATH_EXTACC, '1212OEIC', '5667033ZS')
```

Doesn't work, I get an 'Incorrect Syntax error'.

Thanks

Comment: I should add, unfortunately it is not an option to add the values to the EXTACC table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `UNION` to add the 2 hardcoded values to the resultset that you are passing to the `in` clause.

```
IN (SELECT A_ACCID FROM T_ATH_EXTACC UNION ALL SELECT '1212OEIC' UNION ALL SELECT '5667033ZS')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IN (SELECT '1212OEIC', '5667033ZS', A_ACCID FROM T_ATH_EXTACC )
```

Comment: Why was this upvoted? This won't work. It will pass a result set with 3 columns to the 'in' clause and cause an error. not the two additional rows that are required.